# Append to class if hidden div value is equal to attribute from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I've searched and tried for 2 days now, with no luck whatsoever.

What i'm trying:

I generate several div's through a foreach in xslt, that contains a hidden div where i store a code to match value out of an external xml file on. Something like this:

```
<div class="pakket_content">
    <a href="http://">
        <div class="waardering_wrapper col-xs-12">
            <div class="sterwaardering col-xs-8">
                <img src="http://">
            </div>
            <div class="CODE">CODE</div>
            <div class="waardering col-xs-4">
                <p>-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="waardering pull-right">
                <b>-</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md pull-right col-xs-12">
            Nu boeken!
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Where the div class 'code' contains the code to match on.

The xml that comes out of this is:

```
<entities>
    <accommodation cms-id="458245" external-id="CODE" name="Trip A">
        <destination cms-id="45541" name="Paramaribo" level="destination"/>
        <country cms-id="4545" name="Suriname" level="country"/>
        <accommodation-type>Hotel</accommodation-type>
        <testimonial-count>88</testimonial-count>
        <average-testimonial-score>7.6</average-testimonial-score>
        <deep-link>
            http://link.com
        </deep-link>
        <testimonial-count-per-language>88</testimonial-count-per-language>
        <testimonial-count-all>88</testimonial-count-all>
        <average-testimonial-score-all>7.6</average-testimonial-score-all>
    </accommodation>
</entities>
```

Now i wanted to append the  average-testimonial-score to div "waardering" when the external-id attribute in  equals the value in . But how would i go about that?

I tried with looping through the value of the div class and the attribute, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('accommodation').each(function(index) {
                var cijfer = $(this).find('average-testimonial-score-all').text();

                $('.CODE').each(function(index) {

                    var divcode = $(this).text();

                    $.attr('external-id').each(function(index) {
                        var attrcode = $(this).text();

                        if (divcode == attrcode) {
                            $(".waardering").append(cijfer);
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

With no result. 
Can someone push me in the right direction with this?

Comment: I cannot see any elements with class `accocode`?

Comment: I'm sorry, this meant to be class "CODE", i changed it in the question.

Comment: `$.attr('external-id').each` is completely incorrect line. [Take a look](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) how `.attr()` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Fetching `accommodation` `external-id` in correct way (according to [how](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) `.attr()` is supposed to work), the code works as it should.
- I omitted Ajax request for testing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gpvkku6/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var xml = '<entities><accommodation cms-id="458245" external-id="CODE" name="Trip A"> <destination cms-id="45541" name="Paramaribo" level="destination"/> <country cms-id="4545" name="Suriname" level="country"/>  <accommodation-type>Hotel</accommodation-type> <testimonial-count>88</testimonial-count> <average-testimonial-score>7.6</average-testimonial-score> <deep-link>http://link.com</deep-link> <testimonial-count-per-language>88</testimonial-count-per-language> <testimonial-count-all>88</testimonial-count-all> <average-testimonial-score-all>7.6</average-testimonial-score-all> </accommodation></entities>';

    $(xml).find('accommodation').each(function(index)
    {
        var cijfer = $(this).find('average-testimonial-score-all').text();
        var externalId = $(this).attr("external-id");
        $('.CODE').each(function(index)
        {
            var divcode = $(this).text();
            if (divcode == externalId)
            {
                $(".waardering").append(cijfer);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So only one iteration (on the xml) was actually enough. And yes, i screwd up on the .attr(), good excuse to read up on that again. :) Thank you. One problem persists, though, it now appends all 'cijfer' vars to the code div, instead of the right one per div.Can i distinguish that somehow? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5gpvkku6/1/

Comment: @user3657306 if you want to add only to right next `waardering`, you can use `.next()`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gpvkku6/3/). If you want to add to both next `waardering` (`col-xs-4` and `pull-right`), you can use `.siblings()`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gpvkku6/4/).